# How to apply function to data frame column to created iterated column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have IDs with system event times, and I have grouped the event times by id (individual systems) and made a new column where the value is 1 if the eventtimes.diff() is greater than 1 day, else 0 . Now that I have the flag I am trying to make a function that will be applied to groupby('ID') so the new column starts with 1 and keeps returning 1 for each row in the new column until the flag shows 1 then the new column will go up 1, to 2 and keep returning 2 until the flag shows 1 again.

I will apply this along with groupby('ID') since I need the new column to start over again at 1 for each ID.

I have tried to the following:

```
def try(x):
    y = 1
    if row['flag']==0:
        y = y
    else:
        y += y+1 

df['NewCol'] = df.groupby('ID')['flag'].apply(try)
```

I have tried differing variations of the above to no avail.  Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Also, feel free to let me know if I messed up posting the question.  Not sure if my title is great either.

Comment: Not 100% sure if understand your problem, so if add some 10 rows data with 2 groups for better explain it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering + [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) what is much faster solution as loopy `apply` :

I think you need for count only `1` per group and if no `1` then `1` is added to output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'],
    'flag': [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
})


df['new'] = (df[df['flag'] == 1].groupby('ID')['flag']
                                .cumcount()
                                .add(1)
                                .reindex(df.index, fill_value=1))
print (df)
  ID  flag  new
0  a     0    1
1  a     0    1
2  a     1    1
3  a     1    2
4  b     0    1
5  b     0    1
6  b     1    1
7  b     1    2
8  b     1    3
```

Detail:

```
#filter by condition
print (df[df['flag'] == 1])
  ID  flag
2  a     1
3  a     1
6  b     1
7  b     1
8  b     1

#count per group
print (df[df['flag'] == 1].groupby('ID')['flag'].cumcount())
2    0
3    1
6    0
7    1
8    2
dtype: int64

#add 1 for count from 1
print (df[df['flag'] == 1].groupby('ID')['flag'].cumcount().add(1))
2    1
3    2
6    1
7    2
8    3
dtype: int64
```

If need count `0` and if no `0` is added `-1`:

```
df['new'] = (df[df['flag'] == 0].groupby('ID')['flag']
                                .cumcount()
                                .add(1)
                                .reindex(df.index, fill_value=-1))
print (df)
  ID  flag  new
0  a     0    1
1  a     0    2
2  a     1   -1
3  a     1   -1
4  b     0    1
5  b     0    2
6  b     1   -1
7  b     1   -1
8  b     1   -1
```

---

Another 2 step solution:

```
df['new'] = df[df['flag'] == 1].groupby('ID')['flag'].cumcount().add(1)
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(1).astype(int)
print (df)
  ID  flag  new
0  a     0    1
1  a     0    1
2  a     1    1
3  a     1    2
4  b     0    1
5  b     0    1
6  b     1    1
7  b     1    2
8  b     1    3
```